# Complex polynominals of degree 2 or less

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ be the complex vector space of complex polynomials of degree 2 or less. Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}, \alpha\neq\beta$. Consider the function $L:P_3(\mathbb{C}) \mapsto \mathbb{C}^2$ given by

$L(p)=\begin{bmatrix}
    p(\alpha)       \\
    p(\beta)\\
\end{bmatrix},$ for $p\in P_3(\mathbb{C})$

1) Explain how L is a linear transformation

---

I know that for a function to be a linear transformation it must satisfy the following:

$1$. $\{0\}\in L$

$2$. $l_1+l_2=l_3\in L$ (closure under vector addition)

$3$. $cl\in L$ (closure under scalar multiplication)

But as I'm asked to explain and not show how L is a linear transformation I'm thinking I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is not a set ! $L$ is a mapping ! You have to show, that for all $p,q \in P_3(\mathbb{C})$ and all $\delta, \gamma \in \mathbb C$ we have

$L(\delta p + \gamma q)= \delta L(p)+ \gamma L(q)$.

Comment: So if for all $p,q \in P_3(\mathbb{C})$ and all $\delta, \gamma \in \mathbb C$ we have

$L(\delta p + \gamma q)= \begin{bmatrix}
    (\delta p+\gamma q)(\alpha)      \\
     (\delta p+\gamma q)(\beta)\\
\end{bmatrix}= ... = \delta L(p)+ \gamma L(q)$

Something like that? (I lack characters in the comments)

Comment: Yes, something like that ....

Comment: Thank you @Fred. I have an additional question. On the wikipedia article about linear transformations it is also referred to as linear mapping. For a linear mapping it has to be closed under both addition and multiplication and not only addition. Can you explain why you in this case only have to show it for addition?